# Identify 'Current' open workspace through TFS API?

Tags: api, tfs

Is there a way to programatically determine the current workspace of the open sln/proj in visual studio using the TFS API? I've seen how the VersionControlServer can retreive all of the known workspaces, but is there anything I can use to tie that to what the user currently has (or doesn't have) open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can determine the physical path of the solution or project file, then you can query that file in TFS and you should see which workspace has been mapped to that local file location.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that the mapped path for a workspace had to be unique, but it makes sense. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

There is another override to the `GetWorkspace` method of an instantiated `VersionControlServer` object.  You can call `GetWorkspace` with the local path like Bernhard states, but you can also call it with the workspace name and workspace owner.  Since the workspace name defaults to the local computer name, you can usually get away with using `Environment.MachineName`, but there is always going to be that developer who changes the workspace name.

Example:

```
TeamFoundationServerFactory _tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(server);
            _tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

VersionControlServer _vcs = (VersionControlServer)_tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
Workspace _ws = _vcs.GetWorkspace(Environment.MachineName, Environment.UserName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the approach from Dave Teply is that it assumes you already have an instance of a `VersionControlServer` or at least the `TeamFoundationServerUri`.

There is a more powerful way though, [using the `Workstation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation.aspx). [Ricci Gian Maria has written a quite extensive blog post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/09/13/how-to-get-tfs-server-address-from-a-local-folder-mapped-to-a-workspace/) about this topic. The below snippet is the essentials of that post:

Use the Workstation class to get the WorkspaceInfo for the path you're looking for, this will search the workpaces for all TFS servers registered on that workstation to see if there's a match:

```
Workstation workstation = Workstation.Current;
WorkspaceInfo info = workstation.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(path);
```

Now that you have the WorkspaceInfo, you can sue it to connect to TFS, the workspace info contains the ProjectCollectionUri for that specific team project collection. And from that the Workspace instance:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(info.ServerUri);
Workspace workspace = info.GetWorkspace(collection);
```

Use the collection or the workspace to then get access to the VersionControlServer:

```
VersionControlServer versionControlServer = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```